# Docker CLI env var value override not respected by container on startup

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using the following Dockerfile to build an image.  The image compiles just fine.

```
FROM java:8u40-jdk

ENV CATALINA_HOME="/usr/local/tomcat" 
ENV PATH=$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"

WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME

ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR 8
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION 8.0.20
ENV TOMCAT_DL_URL http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR/v$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz
ENV TOMCAT_ENV local
RUN set -x \
    && curl -fSL "$TOMCAT_DL_URL" -o tomcat.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvf tomcat.tar.gz --strip-components=1 \
    && rm bin/*.bat \
    && rm tomcat.tar.gz

### remove the closing tag, then use the echo|tee pattern to build it back in
RUN sed -i 's|</tomcat-users>| |' $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml
RUN echo "<role rolename=\"admin\" />" | tee -a $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml \
    && echo "<user username=\"${MANAGER_USER:-admin}\" password=\"${MANAGER_PW:-password}\" roles=\"standard,manager,admin,admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script\"/>" | tee -a $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml \
    && echo "</tomcat-users>" | tee -a $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml

### setup setenv.sh
RUN echo "CATALINA_PID=\"\$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.pid\"" | tee $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh
RUN echo "CATALINA_OPTS=\"\$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Denv=$TOMCAT_ENV \
  -Dlogging_override=file://$CATALINA_HOME/logging_override.xml \
  -Doverride_file=$CATALINA_HOME/override.properties\"" | \
    tee -a $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh \
    && chmod 755 $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

When I run the image, I often want/need to change the value of the TOMCAT_ENV environment variable declared in the dockerfile.  However, when I run a command such as:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d -e TOMCAT_ENV=dev --name tc tomcat
```

The overridden value provided on the command line isn't respected, and the default value "local" is used.

I'm using Docker 1.7.0.

If you know a little about Tomcat, you can see that I'm somewhat clunkily trying to establish a login for the Manager UI, and trying to assemble a setenv.sh file without adding a file from a filesystem.  Perhaps I should do this a different way - if you're aware of a "better" way please educate me.  The goal of my asking this question is to have the runtime override setting of this variable be respected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TOMCAT_ENV` environment variable is used during build time to create `setenv.sh`. It looks something like this:

```
ATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Denv=local -Dlogging_override=file:///logging_override.xml -Doverride_file=/override.properties"
```

You are changing this variable at runtime, but `setenv.sh` already created at this time and the environment is set to `local`.

If you want to change the environment at runtime you should not write the value of the variable `TOMCAT_ENV` to `setenv.sh`, but a reference to the variable. You can do that by escaping the variable in your Dockerfile by prepeding `$TOMCAT_ENV` with a slash to `\$TOMCAT_ENV`:

```
RUN echo "CATALINA_OPTS=\"\$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx1024m - Denv=\$TOMCAT_ENV \
  -Dlogging_override=file://$CATALINA_HOME/logging_override.xml \
  -Doverride_file=$CATALINA_HOME/override.properties\"" | \
    tee -a $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh \
    && chmod 755 $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh
```

Now your `setenv.sh` looks like this:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Denv$TOMCAT_ENV -Dlogging_override=file:///logging_override.xml -Doverride_file=/override.properties"
```

Comment: Thanks for finding what I was obviously missing.  A note for anyone who reads this in the future; the `setenv.sh` will still include the `$TOMCAT_ENV` variable. Inspect the process with `ps` and it will show the correct interpolation.